# Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-66-jsc.aar (Self Answered Question)

Tags: react-native

It happen when you init rn project with react native version 0.66. Just init your project with react-native init newproject --version 0.65.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has resolved in react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-beta.2 release.

Comment: It did solved it for me but now I'm back to "attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()'on a null object reference"